# What is the correct way to say "Noctis Avem"?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, grammar-choice, animals

I'm looking to use "Night bird" as a name or title for something. I don't know which, if any, of the following would be correct:

- Noctis Avem
- Avem Noctis
- Avis Noctem
- Avem nox
- etc.

What rules come into play when this is being used as a name or title of something, and is there more than one correct way to phrase it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to say "night bird" with the words "night" (*nox*) and "bird" (*avis*), you should say "bird of the night", *avis noctis*.
When you decline this expression, *noctis* (of the night) remains in the genitive case whereas *avis* takes the required case.

A more Latin way would be to use an adjective.
I would go with *nocturnus* (nightly, nocturnal or nighttime).
Thus "night bird" would be *avis nocturna* (literally "nightly bird").
Here both words are declined, since we have an adjective attribute.

If you want to use it as a title, the nominative (undeclined) case is the best choice.
Therefore I suggest ***avis nocturna***.

Answer (score 5):

I second the recommendation of *avis nocturna*. (It would also be possible to say *nocturna avis*.)

If you wanted something more poetic, you could also go with something like *avis tenebrosa*, which would translate to something like "gloomy bird" or "bird of gloom" or "dark bird."

Comment: For poetic flair, very little beats _vespertina_ (although it may be hard to fit it into the metre)...

Answer (score 4):

«Noctis avem», in Ovid's Metamorphoses XI 24, about (presumably) an owl.

Comment: This is a perfect find, but could you expand your answer so it is a little less elliptical?

Comment: I second @brianpck: Those two words from Ovidius might be what lead to the mistranslation in the question, and it would be nice to flesh that story out a little. But this is indeed a great find!